# How to use event delegation in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

```
elem.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    if(e.target && e.target.matches("span#save-icon")){
      var HEX = e.target.parentNode.innerHTML.split('span')[2].split('>')[2].split('<')[0];
      save_to_my_space(HEX);
      console.log(HEX);
    }
  });
```

Here `elem` is a parent div which has 8 children, I am using delegated events on all children elements of `elem`. Whenever I fire an event by clicking one of the child of `elem` event gets fired multiple times equal to the number of children `elem` has. How to solve this issue?

Comment: Simply prevent the event delegation `event.stopPropagation();`.

Comment: And, in the future, please post the relevant HTML and CSS as well.

Comment: Thanks, but how to use event.stopPropagation();? I am using Vanilla JS

Comment: In your case it would be `e.stopPropagation();` as `e` is the _event_ also @DanielH Why would you post a link to the jQuery documentation and not [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) when they're not using jQuery?

Comment: Thank you so much, it solved my problem

Answer (score 4):

Using `event.stopPropagation()` will solve the problem

As mentioned by @George check the docs [here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)

```
elem.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    if(e.target && e.target.matches("span#save-icon")){
      e.stopPropagation()
      var HEX = e.target.parentNode.innerHTML.split('span')[2].split('>')[2].split('<')[0];
      save_to_my_space(HEX);
      console.log(HEX);
    }
  });
```